# Glue avro schema registry with flink and kafka for any object

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, aws-glue

I am trying to registry and serialize an abject with flink, kafka, glue and avro. I've seen this method which I'm trying.

```
Schema schema = parser.parse(new File("path/to/avro/file"));
GlueSchemaRegistryAvroSerializationSchema<GenericRecord> test= GlueSchemaRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forGeneric(schema, topic, configs);
FlinkKafkaProducer<GenericRecord> producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<GenericRecord>(
                kafkaTopic,
                test,
                properties);
```

My problem is that this system doesn't allow to include an object different than **GenericRecord**, the object that I want to send is another and is very big. So big that is too complex to transform to GenericRecord.

I don't find too much documentation. How can I send an object different than GenericRecord, or any way to include my object inside GenericRecord?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but basically the `GlueSchemaRegistryAvroSerializationSchema` has another method called `forSpecific` that accepts `SpecificRecord`. So, You can use avro generation plugin for Your build tool depending on what You use (e.g. for sbt [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro)) that will generate classes from Your avro schema that can then be passed to `forSpecific` method.

Comment: I'm trying `forSpecific` too, but I think is too complex, It needs to implement `SpecificRecord` and needs a specific implementation for get() and put(), ***it needs to number each field to recognize data!!*** and I'm not sure how to do it for each child/nested class. I think it should be easier... in fact it is without glue! I have followed this example [link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/blob/v1.1.5/avro-flink-serde/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/services/schemaregistry/flink/avro/User.java)

Comment: From what You are saying it seems that You are trying to use standard classes that are not avro generated and are a standard case class. Since You have the avro schema, You can use different libraries and plugins like https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro that will allow You to automatically generate Java sources for given schema.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard class. At last I'll use the `extends SpecificRecordBase`. It obliges me to implement `get` and `put` methods, but I think it will be the best approach. As I see, avro obliges to send data in order, that is why it needs to set those methods, so I don't see a better way (it is necessary to number fields!).